Why don't image load requests show up in network requests for me?
I need an explanation on how browsers (Chrome/FF) load CSS images.
According to my current knowledge, images used by CSS as background-image, appear in the network tab as requests, with according CSS file as Initiator.
My current experience doesn't cover this - I experience images, which are loaded by CSS and are visible on the page (non-lazy, above-the-fold, incognito window, DevTools with disabled cache) - but not present in the list of requests in the network tab. Certainly it goes about this page: https://www.arag.de/rechtsschutzversicherung/, about this image, on the very top of the page, as on screenshot - it doesn't appear in the Network tab as request.

My issue: I try to count images on the page, with two  console Javascripts. Nor both Javascripts, neither Network tab lists those affected images.
And so I need an explaination of browser working to understand, how can it happen, that some images don't appear as requests, despite they are loaded by CSS with background:(img).
Here are Javascripts I count images:

For background images:



var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
  backgrounds = [];
for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (window.getComputedStyle(elems[i], null).getPropertyValue('background-image') != 'none') {
    backgrounds.push(window.getComputedStyle(elems[i], null).getPropertyValue('background-image'));
  }
}
console.log(backgrounds);




For img



var imageSearch = {
  image_array: {},
  valid_image_nodes: ["DIV", "P", "SECTION", "SPAN"],
  scan_for_valid_images: function(node) {
    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
      if (node.nodeName === "IMG") {
        this.image_array[node.getAttribute("src")] = true;
      } else {
        if (this.valid_image_nodes.indexOf(node.nodeName) !== -1) {
          div_style = node.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(node, false);
          if (div_style.backgroundImage !== "none") {
            url = div_style.backgroundImage;
            this.image_array[url.slice(4, url.indexOf(')'))] = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    var children = node.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      this.scan_for_valid_images(children[i]);
    }
  },
  get_image_array: function() {
    return Object.keys(this.image_array)
  }
}
imageSearch.scan_for_valid_images(document);
imageSearch.get_image_array()




If I go to that url, I DO see the image you mention in the network tab. library/.../bg-schraffur-gelb.png. So I guess the browser still uses some cache?

This is other image.  If you mouseover to this image in the Elements/Styles you'll see the image name is bg-schraffur-gruen.png

@RobbyCornelissen understand. What happens to such images in fact? Are they neverthenless downloaded, even if some more specific CSS rules set them off?

The cached images won't be re-downloaded, so they won't appear in the network tab. So these images do not affect the loading, but their status appears as: "200 OK (from disk cache)".
You need to check :before and :after pseudo-elements separately because they are not standalone HTML elements, but rather parts of an element.


var elems = document.querySelectorAll('*'),
  backgrounds = [];

elems.forEach(function(elem) {
  var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem),
      backgroundImage = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('background-image');

  // If the background image of the element is not 'none', add it to the backgrounds array
  if (backgroundImage !== 'none') {
    backgrounds.push(backgroundImage);
  }

  // Check if there is a ::before pseudo-element and its background image
  var beforeBackgroundImage = window.getComputedStyle(elem, ':before').getPropertyValue('background-image');
  if (beforeBackgroundImage && beforeBackgroundImage !== 'none') {
    backgrounds.push(beforeBackgroundImage);
  }

  // Check if there is an ::after pseudo-element and its background image
  var afterBackgroundImage = window.getComputedStyle(elem, ':after').getPropertyValue('background-image');
  if (afterBackgroundImage && afterBackgroundImage !== 'none') {
    backgrounds.push(afterBackgroundImage);
  }
});

console.log(backgrounds);
.example-div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/200');
}
<div class="example-div"></div>




So far I know, cached images do appear in the Network tab - with a note like "cached". Am I wrong? And: what happens to such images, if I set DevTools to "disable cache"?

BTW. if I count images with your script, the affected image bg-schraffur-gruen.png appears not on the list...

Yes, I worded it poorly. So they do appear, but they have no download time, instead, you see them with this status: "200 OK (from disk cache)".

I looked at the page you linked. You did indeed set bg-schraffur-gruen.png on the div.ico.c2 class, but the div.ico.no class also overrides this, so the div background-image final value will be none, not the mentioned PNG.

The div.ico:before does not have a background. Instead, it displays a character from a font set containing icons, which is how the checkmark appears on the page. In reality, it's a character from a font set, so it's impossible to detect it as an image because completely different search criteria need to be applied.

In the photo you mentioned, it's clearly visible that the background applies not to the :before pseudo-element but to the div marked with the class itself. In this case, the background does not inherit, unlike, for example, the text color. ------ Chrome also faintly highlights it for you. Fading indicates that this rule was not inherited from the parent. However, in the case of pseudo children, the browser always tries to share as much information with you about the parent as possible.

@Evgeniy - As a test, I removed the "no" class from one of the icons. The image appeared as expected. Following this, I ran my script, and the bg-schraffur-gruen.png image appeared once in it.

Its not actually addressing your exact question, but it also does. You asked "How works browser with CSS images?" and you got a great answers for the problem you faced and described.
I thought it would be good to add that the browser will not download images if they are not display in DOM or their class is not being used. Moreover,  will work differently to that. Hope I did not miss a case example down below.


<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style>
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.image1 {
  background-image: url(https://th.bing.com/th?id=ORMS.4324f896b3fcd24d2fbd23f4acee8b3f&pid=Wdp&w=300&h=156&qlt=90&c=1&rs=1&dpr=1&p=0);
}
.image2 {
  background-image: url(https://www.bing.com/th?id=OAIP.45a4437adbcef2ae612a99c27810bd77&pid=AdsNative&c=3&w=300&h=157&dynsize=1&qlt=90);
}
.image3 { // Will NOT be download
  background-image: url(https://www.bing.com/th?id=OAIP.4e625d775faf9aa660301445beb1fc58&pid=AdsNative&c=3&w=300&h=157&dynsize=1&qlt=90)
}
img, div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="image1"></div> <!-- Will be download -->
<div class="image2 hidden"></div><!-- Will NOT be download -->
<div class="hidden"><!-- Will be download --><img src="https://th.bing.com/th?id=ORMS.deac19c7d112dcb8e985ebf6adef0364&pid=Wdp&w=300&h=156&qlt=90&c=1&rs=1&dpr=1&p=0" />
</div>
<img class="hidden" src="https://th.bing.com/th?id=ORMS.d36222a0f85043d70adee0486aa6679d&pid=Wdp&w=300&h=156&qlt=90&c=1&rs=1&dpr=1&p=0" /><!-- Will be download -->
</body>
</html>




browser will not download images if they are not display in DOM or their class being used - this is very interesting statement. Do you maybe have a link to any docu for this?

@Evgeniy - tbh, it was very long time ago and I didn't find the actual post/guidelines that I read about it (and saw in practice during my work), but I think this could be a great post to read more about it - https://csswizardry.com/2018/06/image-inconsistencies-how-and-when-browsers-download-images/
